# how to read python tools from dependencies of json file and install it while python unpackaging?

Tags: python, json, installation, packaging

I am building a python tool to install many pypi libraries at once from json files. For example:This is json file with following dependencies:

```
{
"dependencies": {
        "beautifulsoup4": "^4.4.1",
        "boto": "^2.48.0"
}
}
```

I can import json file to python like:

```
    with open(json_folder+json) as json_file:
         json_data = json.loads(json_file)
         print(json_data)
```

I can't figure out how to install from "dependencies" in json file.

Comment: Hi, could you please add more detail to your question? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @toti08 pleae check now

Comment: Much better, thanks! If you have any doubt about how to ask a good question check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First using that json make a requirements.txt file like this :

```
d = {
    "dependencies": {
       "beautifulsoup4": "^4.4.1",
       "boto": "^2.48.0"
         }
    }

with open("requirements.txt", "w+") as f:
   for i,j in zip(d["dependencies"].keys(), d["dependencies"].values()):
       line = "{}=={}\n".format(i, j.strip("^"))
       f.writelines(line)
```

Then using `pip`(install pip if not) in terminal you can install the dependencies like this :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```